# Live sort query results in php

Tags: php, javascript, json, sorting

I have a query which goes through the table and outputs the data like this:

**Query**

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $array[] = $row;
}

foreach ($array as $key) {
    $name[]    = $key['name'];
    $desc[]    = $key['desc'];
    $cost[]    = $key['price'];
}

$c = 0;
while($c<(count($array))){
    echo 'Name: '.$name[$c].'<br>';
    echo 'Desc: '.$desc[$c].'<br>';
    echo 'Price: '.$cost[$c].'<br><br>';
    $c++;
}
```

**Results**

> Name: xyz1
>   Desc: asdxsadasda
>   Price: 999
>
> Name: xyz2
>   Desc: asdxsadasda
>   Price: 333
>
> Name: xyz3
>   Desc: asdxsadasda
>   Price: 666

I want to be able to sort these results based on the price of each item.
Can I output the result in a jSON file and use that to sort the results (live-without loading the page)?

Could you suggest me a better way to sort the results without having to load the page?

Comment: Why not sort by price in the SQL?

Comment: price is just one parameter, i would also like to sort by "brand name alphabetically" and so on.. I can sort it by loading the page again and passing those parameters as variables by using isset method. But I am looking for a way that it can be done directly using javascript or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you MUST sort the array in PHP, after you got the query result, use the `array_multisort` function in PHP (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

However, if your life does not depend on sorting in PHP, sort at the source in your SQL (the way God intended it to be) it's going to be much much faster and it will take the load off the web server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `category` order by products.price, products.name");
```

You choose sort by ASC or DESC

Comment: price is just one parameter, i would also like to sort by "brand name alphabetically" and so on.. I can sort it by loading the page again and passing those parameters as variables by using isset method. But I am looking for a way that it can be done directly using javascript or something similar.

Comment: You choose sort by name change the order by for products.name

Comment: Why when it can all be sorted in SQL and saved into the array using the while loop.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just wanted to know if you could do it locally.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `products` order by price, name
```

Also, your foreach is not needed as you can do your array setup in the while loop.